# Component update/render being triggered

Tags: angular

I've got a service that gets some data asynchronously. It is causing the component to render or so I think. There is only a console.log in the resolve of the promise. Why is this causing the render?

```
constructor(private viewService: viewService) {
    console.log('[MyView component] construction started');

    viewService.getData(1).then(function(result) {
        console.log('[MyView component] got data from service!');
    });

    console.log('[MyView component] construction complete!');
}
```

**Error:**

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'myViewProperty' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (MyViewComponent.html:23)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.es5.js:12806)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12144)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12507)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12439)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12150)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12507)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.es5.js:12465)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12145)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12507)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not enough information. Where do you use `myViewProperty` that causes the error?

Comment: The thing is there is nothing being set in the .then I don't see how it could cause the component to refresh. I'll update the question with the variable

Comment: The completion of a `Promise` or event of an `Observable` causes change detection to run which causes re-render. I guess you get the error even before the response arrives though.

Comment: that's a bingo! i guess that answers my question

Answer (score 0):

Taking a guess you set `myViewProperty` from the Promise's / Observable's completion... Try to implement `On Init` and do so :

```
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
export class EventSelectionSearchComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy { 


    constructor( private viewService: viewService ) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.viewService.getData(1)
        .then( data => {
            this.myViewProperty = data;
        });
    }

    [ ... ]

}
```

The component's Inputs, Outputs or arguments may not be available after the constructor's call. On the other hand, `ngOnInit` a life cycle hook called by Angular2 to indicate that Angular is done creating the component.